# windows console codepage 866

Tags: c++, windows, boost

I'm using a recent version of windows 10. When I tried to run client expample code from [boost  asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime1/src.html)
and got an expected exception on this line:

```
catch (const std::exception& e)
{

    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    return 1;
}
```

It outputs hieroglyphs on console :

```
connect: ╧юфъы■ўхэшх эх єёЄрэютыхэю, Є.ъ. ъюэхўэ√щ ъюья№■ЄхЁ юЄтхЁу чряЁюё эр яюфъы■ўхэшх
```

Default codepage of my console is 866 because i'm using russian windows. So then I changed a codepage to 1251 via

```
chcp 1251
```

message looks fine:

```
connect: Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение.
```

I'm just curious is there any workaround to this without any manipulations with chcp?

Comment: Those don't look like any hieroglyphs I've ever seen!

Comment: Workaround: Stop using the C++ I/O streams library, and use the Unicode version of [WriteConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole). And stop using libraries that believe ANSI encoding to solve any problem.

Comment: This question is a lot less common than it should be.  The text is generated by FormatMessage(), experiment with it the way you see it being used in Boost.  The error code is 10061.  Beware of BOOST_NO_ANSI_APIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it from C++ code then use [SetConsoleOutputCP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleoutputcp) for it.

Comment: That's only half of the solution. You're also going to have to make sure, that the locale used by the ASIO library, and the locale used by the C++ I/O streams match the respective code page. Arguably, it's just a lot easier to not rely on ANSI encoding at all.

Comment: Since exception::what returns char* that is likely provided by OP, there is of course possible to use  SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_OEMCP) then MultiByteToWideChar and then std::wcerr to support most unicode, but I got impression that what was needed was just Windows Cyrillic code page 1251.

Comment: Correct. Until that code runs on some else's machine. And then you have to make sure that all 3 parties agree on the same code page as well. This will inevitably break. This is an issue that should be raised with the ASIO library authors: Don't try to localize exception messages. You only have ASCII at your disposal. Unless you want to make your users suffer.

Comment: So to convert message to unicode I should somehow determine what ascii codepage uses asio then translate message to wchar_t via winapi function and then output it to console via widechar version of output stream?

Comment: @alexfsx: Well, no. Talk to the ASIO library authors, and let them know, that exception messages are not user-facing, and should not be localized. Have them give you ASCII text, in plain English, and you will not have to deal with console codepages, locales, or conversions.